# When is the intersection of a normal subgroup with a subgroup normal in group?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group. Let $N$ be a normal subgroup and $H$ be a subgroup of it. Then it is a well-known fact that $N \cap H$ is normal in $H.$

But I was wondering under what conditions is $N \cap H$ normal in the whole of $G?$

One obvious observation is that if $G'\subseteq H,$ then it holds true. Are there some other general conditions that I am missing?

Any help or reference would be highly appreciated!

Comment: In general, if $H$ is a characteristic subgroup of $K$ and $K$ is normal in $G$ then $H$ is normal in $G$. That's because every inner automorphism restricts to an automorphism of $K$.

Comment: I am sorry, what is K here?

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying. Here $H \leq K \leq G$ is a chain of subgroups of $G$. In your case, if $N \cap H$ is characteristic in $N$ then it is normal in the whole group.

Comment: If $H$ is normal? In general $H\cap N$ won't even be normal in $N$, let alone $G$.

Comment: Yes it is not true in general. I am asking for any conditions on H and N that make it happen.

Comment: I understand; but the thing is that *most of the time* it won''t even be normal in $N$, and so it won't even be normal in $\langle H,N\rangle$, let alone in $G$. You're not going to be able to put any "local" conditions on that intersection; saying $G'\subseteq H$ is just a special case of $H$ itself being normal, and I don't think you'll be able to get the desired conclusion otherwise: again, you would need $H\cap N$ to be, first of all, normal in $N$.

Comment: In short, I think normality of $N$ is a red herring: for one, if you take $N=G$, then the answer is "precisely when $H$ is normal". For other $N$, you might get lucky and just happen to "cut out" a characteristic subgroup of $N$, but that will be more happenstance and coincidence than the result of something general.